# What if the world was basically reset but people still remembered things?

Tags: society, technology, humans, culture

In my story, the world has come to a point where technology has advanced a bit farther than what we have now but the ecosystem is in a terrible state. With the aid of magic, one of the characters manages to reverse the effect humanity has had on the planet, basically removing anything that harmed the world or that people have done. Geography is altered, houses vanish, communication is shut down. All there is is the people and animals. Magic is gone too, it was all used to destroy technology. 
The result is that the people are no longer united and technology is nonexistent, but aside from that, what major things would happen? What would the world look like?

Comment: *"There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.  There is another theory which states that this has already happened."*

Comment: I think this post is a bit premature, and certainly too broad and hypothetical. The proper approach would be for you to spend some time thinking about what would happen to ~7.5 billion people who suddenly have no food, no shelter, and no tools with which to acquire either of the first two things. If you still want to write a story where that happens, you should have some more specific questions.

Comment: Hi Asher, welcome to Worldbuilding! While this is a cool idea, it’s currently a bit too broad to be answered specifically and helpfully. We call these kinds of questions “[high-concept](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions)” questions. Is there a specific, answerable problem that your having while constructing such a world? Maybe how long it’d take to rebuild? Until it’s clearer, I’ve voted to place your question on hold so you don’t get swamped with unhelpful answers.

Comment: Without changing the minds of the people, those prone to expoit would thank you for giving them the wealth of a world to exploit and the advanced knowledge to do it quickly and efficiently.  Unity is also a concept of the mind, so each nation would suddenly go beserk re-establishing economies and building defences knowing perfectly well their neighbors are doing the same.  Changing the world doesn't mean much if you don't change people.

Comment: Related: [How many years would it take to reach an industrial revolution level of life from scratch?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/113225/32451)

Comment: Since there was no consequence to ruining the ecosystem, why won't folks do it again? You say "magic is gone, too", but why should we believe it? Turning a blind eye to *ruining the ecosystem* was much harder, but folks still did it. Maybe there's other magic out there to be discovered - a problem for future generations.

Answer (score 2):

In the short term, you will have chaos, starvation, and fighting over food. B/c so few people know how to get food in the wild. And b/c without modern technology, the planet can sustain a lot fewer people than it has.

Eventually, civilization will rebuild itself. For every piece of technology, there are be people who know how to make it. For every raw material, there are people who know how to obtain them from nature. Your reset will restore all the easily accessible mineral deposits.

It is true that in the first few weeks, brute force will rule. But soon enough, a newly formed tribe of big & strong men will be defeated by a tribe of men who know how to make bows. And they in turn be defeated by whoever learns to make metals.

Nations will re-form, mainly along language boundaries. Economy will be rebuilt, b/c so many people want to be able to buy whatever they need.

Answer (score -1):

Just like a bad dream, the characters remember that reality and history.
The traumas are different from one person to other. Some people see it as a new opportunity but for other is like death, to be in a place we're they don't want to be, yes, everything around "is better" but is not what they want.
*People be people*, so the criminals or "bad" people are the ones that are trying to take advantage(once again?)...
The world looks like a desert(Mars) or mostly water(Neptune).